# email error message stating missing or invalid fields

Tags: error, unsubscribe

Mailing cannot be sent. There are missing or invalid fields (body_html:action.optOutUrl or action.unsubscribeUrl).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you override this, CiviMail requires a token to be included either for folk to Opt Out or Unsub

Hopefully you will find what you need in the documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/what-you-need-to-know/